# AngularJS ng-show is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to make the button "Detalhes" to toggle a div to show a message.

Apparently there's nothing wrong.
First... my HTML

```
            <tr ng-repeat="chamado in cabertos">
                            <td>{{chamado.numero}}</td>
                            <td>{{chamado.user}}</td>
                            <td>{{chamado.assunto}}</td>
                            <td>{{chamado.status_chamado}}</td>
                            <td><button ng-click="mostra()">Detalhes</button></td>
                        </tr>                               
                    </tbody>
                    <div ng-show="{{visivel}}">
                        <h3>Mensagem enviada:</h3>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </div>
                 </table>
            </div>
```

My Script:

```
app.controller('mostra',function($scope){       
    $scope.visivel = false;
    $scope.mostra = function() {
        if($scope.visivel==false) $scope.visivel=true;
        else if($scope.visivel == true) $scope.visivel=false;
    };
});
```

And the when I press F12 in my page, for an unknown reason there is a ng-hide not allowing me to toggle my div:

```
<div ng-show="false" class="ng-hide">
                        <h3>Mensagem enviada:</h3>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Change

```
<div ng-show="{{visivel}}">
```

To

```
<div ng-show="visivel">
```

Edit - adding explanation why this is the case. I am quoting Evan, as I could not explain this any better than he.

**Why is this?**

> The $scope.visive1 variable does not need to be interpolated through
>   the use of double-brackets in the ng-show directive. **In short
>   Directives do not need braces, while expressions DO need them**
>   - @Evan Bechtol

Comment: You should explain why this is, so that he understands what is incorrect about his attempt:  The `$scope.visive1` variable does not need to be interpolated through the use of double-brackets in the `ng-show` directive.  In short **Directives do not need braces, while expressions DO need them**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Evan, and thanks for the help Brian. ;) It worked

Comment: @brianslattery thanks for the quote, you should update it though, as I clarified my comment to be slightly more correct. Expressions also have access to the variables within their scopes.

Comment: No problem :). @Evan Bechtol, I've added your explanation as I could not do any better myself. Thank you for the recommendation as well, it will help with better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this

```
ng-show="visivel"
```

and not

```
ng-show="{{visivel}}"
```

Reason why you see class="ng-hide"

since your ng-show is false, angular applies class ng-hide which hides the element as it is opposite of show, if ng-show was true it would have removed the class.

Also you do not need to use the curly braces (interpolation) along with pre defined angular JS directives like ng-show, ng-hide, ng-if, ng-repeat. Angular knows by itself what you passing to these directives

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page you reset the App and therefore you do this:

```
$scope.visivel = false;
```

making the div invisible..

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing  `$scope.visivel = {}` in the controller.

```
app.controller('mostra',function($scope){    
 $scope.visivel = {};   
    $scope.visivel = false;
    $scope.mostra = function() {
        if($scope.visivel==false) $scope.visivel=true;
        else if($scope.visivel == true) $scope.visivel=false;
    };
});
```

Also in the HTML use 
`ng-show="visivel"` instead of  `ng-show="{{visivel}}"`